# Google Apps Script HTML file: Fast way to respond to autocomplete from Google spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-apps-script, autocomplete, google-sheets-api

I am starting to set up an HTML form that teachers can use to enter and upload student observations into a Google spreadsheet, which already contains student names and grade levels. A jQueryUI autocomplete input box will let users select the student by entering the first few letters of the student's name.

The autocomplete is implemented on the server side by using jQuery ajax and a doGet() to receive the search string. With each ajax call, all 1,000 student names and grades are pulled from a sheet range into a master array of student objects (records). A regex search of that master array is used to add matching records to another array, which is then passed back as a JSONP to the calling HTML for autocomplete to use. That is all working -- but with 1,000 students, it is SLOW, taking up to 30 seconds to respond to a keystroke.

This seems inefficient. Here are the options I can think of:

1. Create the master array when the HTML form is written, and then make it session-persistent on either the server or client side. Can I create a persistent Javascript object in a Google Apps server script?
2. Pass the search string to a SpreadsheetApp filter function and turn the filtered range into a JSON for return to the client.
3. Pull and pass the entire master array to the client (as hidden HTML?) when the form loads, and perform the autocomplete all client-side.

Does anyone have experience with autocomplete and spreadsheet-based Google scripts? I am enough of a newbie not to want to code all these options just to try them out, if there are obvious winners (or losers) among them.

Is there another approach that I am simply overlooking?

Any advice would be welcome!!

Comment: Any number of methods for building responsive client autocomplete on generic websites is applicable to the sidebar, etc, in Apps Script. Note that you do not need to use `doPost`/`doGet` from an apps script sidebar or webapp - use the `google.script.___` pattern for communication between client and server. If you have no idea what that is, go review the documentation and its examples.

Comment: Thank you! I think I had seen mentions of `google.script.run` but not considered its usefulness to my app. Looks a lot better than what I cobbled together without it.